# Firebase Observe() Clarification

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If you for instance do

```
DataBase.database().refrence().observe(.valueChanged....
//code here
)
```

more then one time in the same spot, does this create a stack of observers? I want to make sure I only have 1 observer per spot. Does calling this method multiple times create more then one observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach multiple observers to the same location in the database, the SDK is smart enough to internally only register with the server to receive updates to that location once.  It doesn't duplicate the amount of data sent to the app.  All your observers at that location will still receive the updates, so you will need to unregister each to stop receiving updates.